# Oracle passing a variable to a function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, data-binding

I have some SQL code, which uses a hard coded date. My goal is to remove the hard coded dates and replace them with variables to make the code generic.

My test CASE is the following;

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IsDate( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER AS
   V_date DATE;
   BEGIN
      V_Date := TO_DATE( p_str, p_format );
       RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN 0;
    END;
```

This works fine

```
   select IsDate(DATE '2021-07-31','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

This causes an error (see below). Can someone please explain the issue and how can it be fixed.
I'm testing on live SQL. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
   exec :my_date :=  DATE '2021-07-31';
   select IsDate( DATE my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

i am getting below error

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
> ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Your procedure takes two `varchar2` input parameters, but you passed `date` as first parameter. Why? Also `date ....` assumes a text constant literal after it because it constitutes a date literal

Comment: what is your oracle version?

Comment: My goal is to get rid of the hard coded date in the calling function and use a variable instead in the calling function.. can you provide a detailed response on how I can accomplish this? I am testing with live sql

Comment: "My goal is to get rid of the hard coded date" - so you need some source of the date-like strings. What is it? Where do your "dates" come from?

Comment: I would like a user to pass in the dates like in my exec example. Maybe I need a PLSQL wrapper to call my sql code? I want my sql code to be variables, not hard coded dates. Bottom line is I don't want users modifying any code. I hope I adequately explained my issue. Thanks for your patience and expertise

Comment: To pass variables from where? SQL doesn't have user interaction mechanism, it need to be provided by the client application

Comment: Will a PLSQL wrapper around my SQL code work? Then I can remove hard coded dates from my sql and use variables instead  The wrapper can take in a start_date and an end_date  if only one date is passed in then the end_date = start_date.

Comment: What is "SQL code"?

Comment: `select IsDate(DATE my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;` fails because dual has no column named `my_date`, the `date` literal is malformed, and your function doesn't take a `date` anyway. Did you mean `select IsDate(:my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;`?

Answer (score 4):

There a special function `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` since 12.2 that does exactly what you want to achieve:
[VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

Example:

```
SQL> select VALIDATE_CONVERSION('01-01-2000' as date,'dd-mm-yyyy') chk1 from dual;

      CHK1
----------
         1

SQL> select VALIDATE_CONVERSION('01-01-2000' as date,'yyyy-mm-dd') chk2 from dual;

      CHK2
----------
         0
```

Also livesql.oracle.com doesn't support `exec` command which is an SQL*Plus command. So if you want to test your functions with bind variables, you can use simple PL/SQL Variables:

```
declare
    string_date varchar2(100);
    
    FUNCTION IsDate( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER AS
        V_date DATE;
    BEGIN
        V_Date := TO_DATE( p_str, p_format );
        RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RETURN 0;
    END;
begin
    string_date:='31-12-2000';
    dbms_output.put_line(IsDate(string_date,'dd-mm-yyyy'));
end;
/
```

Comment: How can I pass 2 dates to sql code? Inside my sql code reference the dates as variables ie start_date, end_date. I'm trying to create generic code. I don't want a user to modify code every time they need a new start_date and end_date. I want them to pass in dates some how. That's what I was trying with the exec command. Thanks for your help and expertise

Comment: @Beefstu pass dates from what? Java, Python, a SQL\*Plus script, another PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: A PLSQL procedure.. I am envisioning using that a a wrapper around my SQL code. Then in my SQL code, I will not need hard coded dates. This way nobody will ever need to edit code if they  want different start_date and end_date Would that work?

Comment: @Beefstu the procedure could return a ref cursor. Would that do?

Comment: @ William I'm using a pipeline proc to generate date ranges, range which works great and don't want to change. Since the comments here are limited perhaps I should start a new thread

Comment: @William Robertson this is what I was trying to do   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519898/oracle-creating-procedure-calling-a-function

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE` keyword expects a **literal**, you cannot use a string variable.

Regarding your function:

```
FUNCTION IsDate( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER
```

It expects two `VARCHAR2`, i.e. string values. However when you run `IsDate(DATE '2021-07-31','YYYY-MM-DD')` the you pass a `DATE` value into the function, not a string.

Checking the format of a `DATE` value is pointless, because a `DATE` values itself has no format, it is stored as an internal binary value. Never use `TO_DATE` on a value which is already a `DATE`. Function `TO_DATE` expects a string which shall be converted to a `DATE`.

What is **displayed** when you select a `DATE` is defined (by default) with your current user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. You can change the default output format for example with `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY';` or you set it explicitly by using the [TO_CHAR()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) function.

When you call your function `IsDate(DATE '2021-07-31','YYYY-MM-DD')` then Oracle makes an implicit cast to a string. i.e. it runs

```
V_Date := TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(p_str, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')), p_format );
```

When you pass a `DATE` value, then your function actually acts like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IsDate( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN NUMBER AS
   ret NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   INTO ret
   FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
   WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
     AND VALUE = p_format;
   RETURN ret; 
   -- p_str is ignored completely
END;
```

Note, in Oracle 18 the `TO_DATE` function provides the `DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause, so it may be an overkill to write the extra function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. My goal is trying to get rid of the hard coded date parameter in the calling code and reference as a variable in the calling codeinstead of a literal. Can this be done? If so can you provide an end to end example. I tried your function in my example and it didn't work in live sql

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "get rid of the hard coded date parameter in the calling code". Do you have an example?

Comment: My original post shows the example look at the second scenario that gave the error. Also livesql.oracle.com doesn't support exec command which is an SQL*Plus command. I'm looking to pass a variable to SQL code or create PLSQL set the date and call my SQL code. I don't want a hard coded date in my sql code I want to pass one in. Hope that adds clarity to my request. Thanks for answering

Comment: The second scenario `IsDate( DATE my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` is a SQL syntax error. Fix the code, there is nothing you could prevent by any function. If you like to use a variable, use `IsDate( my_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` - the variable is `my_date`. But as already stated it is completely pointless, there is no format on a `DATE` value you could verify.

Comment: this is what I was trying to do.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519898/oracle-creating-procedure-calling-a-function