# Oracle creating procedure calling a function

Tags: sql, oracle, proc

I have code that works fine in SQL. I am trying to port it to PLSQL and I am unsure how to make it work.

How can I exclude holidays from the list if dates before its populated into the variable l_res. Can use a not exist  or a minus command. Keep in mind there could be several holidays in the table.

Original SQL code I'm trying to port

INSERT INTO timeoff
(employee_id, timeoff_date)
SELECT e.employee_id,
c.date_val
FROM   employees e
INNER JOIN table(generate_dates_pipelined(date '2021-07-08', DATE '2021-07-31')) c
PARTITION BY ( e.employee_id )
ON (SUBSTR(e.work_days, TRUNC(c.date_val) - TRUNC(c.date_val, 'IW') + 1, 1) = 'Y')
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM   holidays h
WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
)
ORDER BY  e.employee_id, c.date_val;

Thanks in advance to all that answer.

```
    create table holidays(
      holiday_date DATE,
     holiday_name VARCHAR2(20)
    );

    INSERT into holidays
      (holiday_date,
       holiday_name)
     VALUES
    (
     TO_DATE('2021/08/01 00:00:00',   'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'August 01 2021');

   INSERT INTO employees                   
 (
   EMPLOYEE_ID,
   first_name, 
   last_name,
   card_num,
   work_days
 )
   WITH names AS ( 
  SELECT 1, 'Jane',     'Doe',      'F123456', 'NYYYYYN'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2, 'Madison', 'Smith', 'R33432','NYYYYYN'
     FROM dual UNION ALL 
     SELECT 3, 'Justin',   'Case',     'C765341','NYYYYYN'
     FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'D564311','NYYYYYN' FROM dual 
    ) SELECT * FROM names;  


  create table timeoff(
         seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    employee_id NUMBER(6),
    timeoff_date DATE,
    timeoff_type VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'V',
     constraint timeoff_chk check (timeoff_date=trunc(timeoff_date, 'dd')),
      constraint timeoff_pk primary key (employee_id, timeoff_date)
     );




    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_date IS OBJECT (
     date_val DATE
    );


    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF obj_date;



    create or replace function generate_dates_pipelined(
            p_from  in date,
            p_to    in date
   )
   return nt_date 
   pipelined
   is
   begin
    for c1 in (
            with calendar (start_date, end_date ) as (
                    select trunc(p_from), trunc(p_to) from dual
                    union all
                    select start_date + 1, end_date
                    from   calendar
                    where  start_date + 1 <= end_date
            )
            select start_date as day
            from   calendar
    ) loop
            pipe row (obj_date(c1.day));
    end loop;

    return;

    end generate_dates_pipelined;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE date_test (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
IS

   l_res  nt_Date;
    

BEGIN
 
  

   SELECT generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date)
     INTO l_res
     FROM DUAL;

   FOR i IN l_res.FIRST .. l_res.LAST
  LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_res (i).date_val);
  END LOOP;
  END;

    EXEC date_test(DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10');
```

Comment: *Can use a not exist or a minus command*... So did you try one of this? What was wrong with that approach?

Comment: I couldn't find any PLSQL examples on how to use the MINUS or not exist command based on my posted code. I want to avoid looping through all the holidays many times and comparing them to each date. Though my test CASE is small, 10 dates and 1 holiday, production will be larger.

Comment: `minus` is a pure SQL set operator, `exists` is a pure SQL predicate. If you make them work in SQL, then you just need to copy the code to PL/SQL as is. Documentation is full of examples:[minus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE), [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXISTS-Condition.html#GUID-20259A83-C42B-4E0D-8DF4-9A2A66ACA8E7)

Comment: SELECT generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date)
         INTO l_res FROM DUAL
       WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM   holidays h
         WHERE  l_res = h.holiday_date);
Errors: PROCEDURE DATE_TEST
Line/Col: 9/8 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 14/23 PL/SQL: ORA-22952: Nested Table equality requires a map method on the element ADT can you tell me what the problem is. That's how I did it in SQL

Comment: Pipelined function is a row source, it should not be specified in select list. Select **from** it. Despite this syntax is allowed (select from dial), it is quite confusing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I also tried casting as table and that also failed. Can you please send me the exact syntax to make the procedure work. I can't seem to get it. It worked before without the not EXISTS logic. I don't understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to select result that function returns *into something*. What? A local variable, for example.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE date_test (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
  2  IS
  3     l_res  nt_Date;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date)
  6       INTO l_res
  7       FROM DUAL;
  8
  9     FOR i IN l_res.FIRST .. l_res.LAST
 10     LOOP
 11        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_res (i).date_val);
 12     END LOOP;
 13  END;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXEC date_test(DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10');
01.08.21
02.08.21
03.08.21
04.08.21
05.08.21
06.08.21
07.08.21
08.08.21
09.08.21
10.08.21

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** If you want to delete dates that exist in the `holiday` table, then this is one option: use the `delete` collection method.

As collection is now sparse, you can't use `FOR` loop to display its values (as you'd get `no_data_found` error) - use `WHILE` instead.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE date_test (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
  2  IS
  3     l_res  nt_date;
  4     i      NUMBER;
  5     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date)
  8       INTO l_res
  9       FROM DUAL;
 10
 11     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('contents of L_RES (all dates) ------------');
 12
 13     FOR i IN l_res.FIRST .. l_res.LAST
 14     LOOP
 15        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_res (i).date_val);
 16     END LOOP;
 17
 18     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('removing holidays -------------------------');
 19
 20     FOR i IN l_res.FIRST .. l_res.LAST
 21     LOOP
 22        SELECT MAX (1)
 23          INTO l_cnt
 24          FROM holidays
 25         WHERE holiday_date = l_res (i).date_val;
 26
 27        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 28           l_res (i).date_val || ': cnt = ' || l_cnt || ' - delete it!');
 29
 30        IF l_cnt = 1
 31        THEN
 32           l_res.delete (i);
 33        END IF;
 34     END LOOP;
 35
 36     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('contents of L_RES (holidays excluded) ----');
 37
 38     i := l_res.FIRST;
 39
 40     WHILE i IS NOT NULL
 41     LOOP
 42        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_res (i).date_val);
 43        i := l_res.NEXT (i);
 44     END LOOP;
 45  END;
 46  /

Procedure created.
```

See it work:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM holidays;

HOLIDAY_DA HOLIDAY_NAME
---------- --------------------
01.08.2021 August 01 2021
05.08.2021 August 05 2021

SQL> EXEC date_test(date '2021-08-01', date '2021-08-10');
contents of L_RES (all dates) ------------
01.08.2021
02.08.2021
03.08.2021
04.08.2021
05.08.2021
06.08.2021
07.08.2021
08.08.2021
09.08.2021
10.08.2021
removing holidays -------------------------
01.08.2021: cnt = 1 - delete it!
02.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
03.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
04.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
05.08.2021: cnt = 1 - delete it!
06.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
07.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
08.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
09.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
10.08.2021: cnt =  - delete it!
contents of L_RES (holidays excluded) ----
02.08.2021
03.08.2021
04.08.2021
06.08.2021
07.08.2021
08.08.2021
09.08.2021
10.08.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you wanted to use `NOT EXISTS`, then this is how to do that:

```
SQL> SELECT date_val
  2    FROM TABLE (
  3            generate_dates_pipelined (DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10'))
  4   WHERE NOT EXISTS
  5            (SELECT 1
  6               FROM holidays h
  7              WHERE date_val = h.holiday_date);

DATE_VAL
----------
02.08.2021
03.08.2021
04.08.2021
06.08.2021
07.08.2021
08.08.2021
09.08.2021
10.08.2021

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: One more question how can I loop through all the values the function returns. l_res(some index)

Comment: As you said - in a loop. I edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks again for your expertise. Greatly appreciated

Comment: I edited my original post to include a holidays table. If I want to exclude a holiday from the output list do I need another loop comparing each date for the match (seems like a waste) or can I do this WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   holidays h
         WHERE  c.date_val = h.holiday_date
       )
That's how I do it my SQL code. Thanks again for your expertise and patience. This exercise is so I don't have hard coded dates like I do in my SQL, which drives me crazy

Comment: Exclude them wherever you want; for example, in a loop, within the `select start_date as day from   calendar` statement.

Comment: I meant how can I exclude them from the l_res variable. I updated your version of the code with holiday information but I'm unsure how to do the exclusion in PLSQL. Apologies for the many questions

Comment: Exclude them BEFORE storing any values into L_RES, which means IN THE FUNCTION.

Comment: I tried excluding them. SELECT generate_dates_pipelined (start_date, end_date) INTO l_res FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM holidays h WHERE l_res = h.holiday_date); Errors: PROCEDURE DATE_TEST Line/Col: 9/8 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Line/Col: 14/23 PL/SQL: ORA-22952: Nested Table equality requires a map method on the element ADT can you tell me what the problem is.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more code. Have a look.

Comment: thank you so much!! For my education can you explain why I was getting errors with my not EXISTS approach I attempted. There is one more step I need to, which involves a join with an employee table and I like to try and take a stab at it. I'll modify the original post with the employees table and ORGANIAL SQL code

Comment: I know the SQL works. The reason I wanted a procedure is so I can pass in the dates, I don't want them hard coded in the procedure. How can I use my original SQL while passing in dates to the procedure. Is that possible? I want to call it like this EXEC date_test(DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-10');

Comment: Just add INTO L_RES in line #1

Comment: I tried that  Since the pipelined function returns more than one row can I use SELECT INTO?

 Do I need to define a date collection and use select ... bulk collect into ?

In sorry for all the elementary questions. I'm a DBA who got a developer tasked thrown at me. A working example of my SQL code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the bulk collect metho worked. Thank you for all your help and expertise